# Insert into script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to add a row to my table named Clienti, I opened query tool and wrote this query, anyway it isn't working, can you tell me the reason? It says the array isn't correctly defined.

```
INSERT INTO "Clienti"(
            "Nome", "Cognome")
    VALUES ('example', 'example2');
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: What, if anything, is the error message?  We can't really help you without knowing that.  And also, tell us which database you are using.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is the row just not inserted?

Comment: I'm using postgres

Comment: @Mureinik I get the error I mentioned, if the script contains an error the query won't be "activated"

Comment: As data type for the columns I chose Character[] with length as 20, could this be a problem?

Comment: @Shark44 can you share the exact error message?

Comment: I can but it is in Italian:
ERRORE:  il letterale array non è definito in modo corretto: "pippo"
LINE 3:     VALUES ('pippo', 'baudo');
                    ^
DETAIL:  L'array deve iniziare con "{" oppure con le informazioni di dimensione.
********** Error **********

ERRORE: il letterale array non è definito in modo corretto: "pippo"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: L'array deve iniziare con "{" oppure con le informazioni di dimensione.
Character: 67

Comment: I think that actually makes sense, but you're showing us the wrong code. Your `insert` statement is fine; the error is in your `create table` definition.

Comment: ```
-- Table: "Clienti"

-- DROP TABLE "Clienti";

CREATE TABLE "Clienti"
(
  "Nome" character(20)[],
  "Cognome" character(20)[]
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Clienti"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Do you guys know why I can't format it as code anymore?

Comment: Because you're typing stuff in the comments instead of adding it to your question.

Comment: You most probably want `varchar(20)` **not** `character(20)[]` And please **[edit]** your question to include additional information. Do not put code into comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your fields are defined as [arrays of strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), not strings. That's why PostgreSQL is complaining about your `INSERT` statement: You're trying to put a single string into a field that's defined as an array of strings.

```
 "Nome" character(20)[]
```

means `Nome` is an array of strings of 20 characters.

You probably want

```
"Nome" varchar(20)
```

(for a string of up to 20 characters)

or

```
"Nome" text
```

(for no length limit).

See [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) for more information about character types.

Answer (score -1):

Try this insert query it will work.

INSERT INTO Clienti(Nome, Cognome)
    VALUES ('example', 'example2');

Comment: it doesn't; it says: "relation to Clienti doesn't exist"